# Where are my model ships?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've been exploring the Normandy SR2, and I've been finding boxes squirreled away containing the model ships I purchased in Mass Effect 2.

Where does each model ship end up (assuming you purchase it in ME2)? I'm having trouble finding the Destiny Ascension, but I think a full list would be good to have regardless.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure if I had *all* of them in ME2, and thus I don't know if they are all there for me to find in ME3, but here are the collectibles I found on the Normandy:

> - **Alliance Shuttle** - CIC: between War Room and Galaxy Map
> - **Destiny Ascension** - Crew Deck:  Life Support
> - **Turian Cruiser** - Engineering: Subdeck Stairwell
> - **Space Hamster** - Engineering: Subdeck Stairwell
> - **Shadowbroker** - Engineering: Subdeck Stairwell
> - **Sovereign** - Engineering: Subdeck Stairwell
> - **Freighter** - Shuttle Bay
> - **Quarian** - Shuttle Bay
> - **Alliance Cruiser** - Shuttle Bay
> - **Geth Cruiser** - Shuttle Bay
> - **Normandy** - Shuttle Bay

That's the master list of what I've found so far, but I also broke it up down below with maps.

Also of note is that the model for the Alliance Kodiak was for sale in my game from Kassa Fabrication shop (accessible at 10% markup from the terminal in the Shuttle Bay). I am not sure if that's the only location for it, or if that's simply where you buy any models that you didn't have from your imported save.

---

### Combat Information Center

> - **Alliance Shuttle** - Between War Room and Galaxy Map

[image]

---

### Crew Deck

> - **Destiny Ascension** - Life Support

[image]

---

### Engineering

> - **Turian Cruiser** - Subdeck Stairwell
> - **Space Hamster** - Subdeck Stairwell, runs across floor, sometimes hides
> - **Shadowbroker** - Subdeck Stairwell
> - **Sovereign** - Subdeck Stairwell

[image]

---

### Shuttle Bay

> - **Freighter**
> - **Quarian**
> - **Alliance Cruiser**
> - **Geth Cruiser**
> - **Normandy**

[image]

---

Comment: Based on the list of models in the [ME2 wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Model_Ships), it looks like I'm missing some. I probably never got them in ME2. I'll be happy to update the list and maps if someone has locations of the ones I'm missing, though. Assuming they exist, I seem to be missing the Normandy, Normandy SR-2, Sovereign, and Turian Cruiser.

Comment: I found Sovereign and the Turian Cruiser down below Engineering, where Jack used to hang out.

Comment: where is the original Normandy?

Comment: I can confirm that I found the Normandy in the shuttle bay, but I can't remember where exactly.  I'm pretty sure it was on the port side though.

Comment: The Normandy is on the same side as the Quarian in a box just before the shuttle.

Comment: @Stephen thanks, I threw something on the map that's hopefully close enough.

Comment: @Sterno Pretty spot on

Comment: You don't have to import a save apparently (as you've noticed in chat)

Comment: @BenBrocka I'm curious which ones you'll find then with an unimported game. There are definitely some that were not on my ship, but were on the ships of others.

Answer (score 2):

The Destiny Ascension is in the room that was Thanes in ME2.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the ones above - i also found a Normady Model in the Shuttle Bay