# What are all the models that Shepard finds for?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I assume that this is some recurring element I don't get, but what are the models for?  I've found a handful of them and saw the completed ones in the Captain's Quarters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models are just collectables and are for fun. You can find a list of them in this question/answer: [Where are my model ships?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53576/7019)