# Which ship models can I find if I don't have a Mass Effect 2 save imported?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The first time I walked around the Normandy I found a ship model, reading [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53576/where-are-my-model-ships) I learned that you can find several models on your ship if you bough them on ME2, I oly found a few of the ships mentioned in the top answer.

Which ships can I find if I don't import a Mass Effect 2 save? Can I find the rest of them by any other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the opportunity to collect all of them.

I have not found them in the same locations but I have found more in stores on the Citadel.

Look at your display case in your quarters and count off how many you have, you'll notice that several showed up without too much effort (if any)

I have not yet found the space hamster however.

Comment: The answer I linked says he's running around Engineering, but I couldn't find him as well.

Comment: @JohnoBoy I may find him later in the game as a lot of the ships didn't show up in shops until a few missions in.

Comment: The hamster is where jack was in mass effect 2 you just have to catch him!

Comment: @Fuktup4 Yes, I just have not seen him in a "new game" in ME3 yet.